# Menu dropdown top and bottom padding issue for items element

Tags: html, css

I am working on a side project HTML and CSS. I did most of the work and I wanted to improve it. Now I'm trying to add a dropdown menu. I did it but the items inside for any reason don't react when I try to add margin-top or padding-top.

here is my code:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.sign-in {
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.test {
  overflow: visible;
}

.drop {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.droper {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 190px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.droper a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.drop:hover .droper {
  display: block;
}

.droper a:hover {
  color: #1c3fa8;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="features.html">Features<span class="arrow"> &#9663;</span></a>
        <div class=" droper">
          <a href="features.html" class="drop-list">Hosting Opt 1</a>
          <a href="features.html" class="drop-list">Hosting Opt 2</a>
          <a href="features.html" class="drop-list">Hosting Opt 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="docs.html">Documentation</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

the result in the browser:
[the link](https://priceless-dijkstra-92895e.netlify.app)

Can someone help me out with what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue, add this block of CSS. This sets the links to display as block.

```
.droper a {
  display:block;
}
```

Here is your snippet with the new class

```css
.droper a {
  display:block;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.sign-in {
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.test {
  overflow: visible;
}

.drop {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.droper {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 190px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.droper a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.drop:hover .droper {
  display: block;
}

.droper a:hover {
  color: #1c3fa8;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="features.html">Features<span class="arrow"> &#9663;</span></a>
        <div class=" droper">
          <a href="features.html" class="drop-list">Hosting Opt 1</a>
          <a href="features.html" class="drop-list">Hosting Opt 2</a>
          <a href="features.html" class="drop-list">Hosting Opt 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="docs.html">Documentation</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```